# What is Laravel Auth Class to Link it to a Controller

Tags: php, laravel, class

What is the class Path for Laravel Auth Class I want it on my Home Controller

```
FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 29: Class 
'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I supose you are using the `Auth` class in your php files. You should place a `\` in front of the class name to let the parse know this is in the root namespace.

For example, like this:

```
\Auth::check();
```

Alternatively, you can add the following line on top of your class:

```
use Auth;
```

This will let the parser know where the Auth class is.

Comment: I have the class path use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;` @Jerodev Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the namespace using `use` statement;

`Use Auth`

OR

Just backlashes it to let it know not to find it in current namespace

`\Auth::login($user)`

Comment: Same answer as @jerodev. Opps